# Pass query params in 'Router module' Routes array and read in component

Tags: angular, routes, angular2-routing

I'm trying to differentiate between the sample companies and other companies. So I'm passing query params to check if it is sample company and check the query param sample if it is true in Route array like this

```
const routes: Routes = [{ path: '',
    component: DefaultComponent,
    children: [
        {path: 'company', redirectTo: 'company-data/1?sample=true'},
        {path:'company/:id', component: CompanyComponent}
]}];
```

How can I read this query param in component and fetch true value for sample company and for other companies that sample will be false. I get undefined if I try to fetch it like this

```
this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
    console.log('Query params ',params['sample']) 
});
```

I don't know if this is right way.

Comment: there's no component for 'company-data/' route?

Comment: @NadunLiyanage It is redirected to company/:id, hence have a component 'CompanyComponent'

Comment: are you always redirecting with id=1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`queryParams` are optional parameters. You do not need to specify them in the Routes module. But for this, you need to be sure that you not only pass the id=1

```
const routes: Routes = [{ path: '',
component: DefaultComponent,
children: [

    {path:'company/:id', component: CompanyComponent}
]}];
```

and you can simply call the component by
 `router.navigate(['/', 'company', 1], { queryParams: { sample: true } });`

Answer (score 0):

import `activatedRoute` from your router module and assign query parameter inside your component

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

export class CompanyComponent { 

  isSample: boolean; 

  constructor(private routeParams: ActivatedRoute) { 
    this.isSample = routeParams.snapshot.params['sample']; 
  }

}
```

Comment: I used this, but it didn't solved my problem. Though I got a way out by nesting my routes and it solved this issue.